# color extending beyond the rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with extending color outside the rounded corners. The problem disappears when the vertical margins (5px) are added to nav li, but then there is visible the color of the second layer. Can you also tell me how to standardize these colors? I define only rgb(244, 228, 228, 0.532) and want the whole navigational menu in this color.

```css
#logo-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(244, 228, 228, 0.532);
    border-radius: 10px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
    display:flex;
    list-style: none; /* Usunięcie domyślnego stylu kropki dla listy */
    padding: 0px;  /* Usunięcie wewnętrznego odstępu dla listy */
    margin-top: 0px; 
    background-color: rgb(244, 228, 228, 0.532);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
    border-left: 2px solid black;   
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
  
nav li {
    display: inline-block; /* Umieszczenie elementów listy obok siebie w jednej linii */
    margin: 0px; /* Odstęp między elementami */
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(244, 228, 228, 0.532);
    color: rgb(244, 228, 228, 0.532);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgb(30, 28, 28);
    transition: color 0.3s ease; /* Dodano efekt przejścia koloru */
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(90, 164, 201); /* Kolor po najechaniu myszką */
  color:rgb(244, 228, 228, 0.532);
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div id="logo-banner">

            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">START</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">OPIS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">HISTORIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">LIVE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">GALERIA ZDJĘĆ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">KONTAKT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding [`overflow: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#hidden) (or [`overflow: clip;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#clip)) to the `<ul>` element's CSS?